# MongoDB deleting Array contant

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to delete array items with my code, nothing works till now.

[image]

PS : the content that needs to be deleted is in `data` array

I try to use code below to do that and it is still not working.

```
newdevice.update({vic_num:vcnm},{ $pull: { "data": [] } },(err,data)=>{
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log(data);
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to initialise with blank array then you can use [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/)

```
newdevice.update({vic_num:vcnm},{ $set: { "data": [] } },(err,data)=>{
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log(data);
        })
```

If you want to use [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) then you have to either provide condition or exact matching value, something like following

```
newdevice.update({vic_num:vcnm},{ $pull: { "data": { $nin: [ 5 ] } } },(err,data)=>{
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log(data);
        })
```

in above example, all data will be removed except 5, please refer [$pull documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/)

Comment: thanks pro its worked by using #set
newdevice.update({vic_num:vcnm},{ $set: { "data": [] } },(err,data)=>{
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log(data);
        })

Answer (score 0):

[You can refer this documentation also $pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/)`newdevice.update({vic_num:vcnm},{ $pull: { "data":{ $in: ["your fields"] } } },(err,data)=>{
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log(data);
        })`